# Unable to find and use integrated webcam on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, webcam, camera

I am unable to use my integrated webcam of my laptop(Note:- It is not broken as it works on windows 11 in my dual boot).
as per a question in community I tried to unable connectivity use

`sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

Please ,give my through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add your userid to the `video` group: `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logout and login. Groups are set up at `login` time.